# Multiple Api calling serialy in angular 6

Tags: angular, angular-http

I am having 20 APIs. My goal is to create a page. When the page will get loaded i want All my APIs to be called and load the data and store it in many array type variables. But if I am calling all the APIs on initialisation its taking too much time to load the page. 
So now i want to call the APIs one by one automatically on page initialisation. Can you please give me some idea how to make these APIs call  one by one serialy.
If i am using if clause i.e *if(respose)* at the end of each API promises the code seems too lengthy.

Comment: If you need to chain them you could use `flatMap()` and chain them like that, do your necessary mapping and store the results and call the next function returning an `Observable`. If you could provide us with some code and examples we could give you advise on other possible approaches.

Comment: Actually this is the requirement. not started coding yet. I have tried to explore using forkJoin(). But still in confusion whether its the right solution or not. One more clue i can give , all the APIs are same just the request parameters are different for each.

Comment: Do you depend on the result from the `Observable` or the function you execute before? Like, do you use the results from the previous function as parameters for the next one? If you haven't started coding yet.. I personally think this looks like some kind of poorly thought design choice. Maybe you can give us some more details about what you are trying to get and achieve with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did solve my own problem.

```
of(...urls).pipe(
  concatMap((url: string) => this.getHTTP.getData(url)))
  .subscribe((result) => {
    this.resultArray.push(result);
    console.log('this.resultArray', this.resultArray);
```

the function concatMap() which allows the urls to hit one after another .For a better understanding i am posting the screenshot of the waterfall of API calls in network.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Why not call the api's or before you actually need them, for example using a resolver to fetch data via api call before a route is loaded. But if you really do need them all at the starting then you maybe need to optimize, or make 1 api call to fetch all the data. Rather than 20.

Resolver with Ng5 example: https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-resolve-guard-example

Search for Resolve: https://angular.io/guide/router

Comment: ohk. I have gone through this . But my concern is to minimize the loading time of the page to which i am rendering. The loading time is now more because at the time of loading it is fetching all the APIs. So here the solution is , may be we should call the APIs just after oninit() so that the page will be loaded without delay and in the background the APIs will be called.

Comment: "This tells Angular that we must wait for NewsResolver’s resolve() method to return data before we display the NewsComponent"   Its there inside the description of the link You have provided. It means before loading the new page it will wait for the data to get loaded. It means it will take more time.. This is my view.. If wrong please correct me

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't have any code to show us, I made a little stackblitz to show you how to do this with `mergeMap` or `forkJoin` using single functions that return an `Observable` and using `mergeMap`, `forkJoin` or `concatMap` using an array of IDs to call the function dynamically.

See, `mergeMap` will execute the code you have and track them independendly, so the order of the return of your function will not be necessarily the same. `concatMap` respects this and tries to execute them in order. `forkJoin` will patiently wait until all of them are finished and then return you an `Observable` which you can subscribe to and get an array of all the return values of the `Observable` your function returned.

It's best if you take a look at the code and click through once or twice. [Here is the stackblitz.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ove1qf)

You might wanna look at `concatAll` too, you could make an Observable containing inner Observables and use `concatAll` to automatically subscribe to the next Observable in order after the previous one finishes, [here the link to learnrxjs.io](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/concatall.html), a really good source for beginners.

Hope this helps.